# Label not listed for table while using Kile

Tags: cross-referencing, input, kile, auto-completion

I am using Kile on Ubuntu 12.04 for a project.

I have a table in a separate file from the main document. This table has a label

```
\label{table}
```

The table is called by the document with

```
\input{table}
```

This works fine, the table is properly integrated to the document.

Usually, Kile lists all possible references throughout the project when opening a

```
\ref{}
```

environment. In this case, it doesn't work.

Would you have an idea for this issue? It is a big project and I don't intend to remember by heart all labels!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have two comments: **(1)** I think it would be better to add the table using `\input` rather than `\include`. The latter should be really used only for whole chapters. **(2)** There are two options: Either Kile is able to recognize refs from included or input files (and someone will have an answer) or it is not (and then the question would be a feature request, which can't be really solved here).

Comment: Thanks, you're right @yo'. I actually used `\input` and not `\include` which I use for chapters. I'll edit!
Hum, alright, you're probably right about this... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option I use is that I separate only the table contents into another file, which gives IMHO a clearer source code, moreover, the labels are kept in place. Like this:

Main file `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}

As we see in Table~\ref{tab:bla}, all blas have a bla.

\begin{table}
\input{tab-bla}
\caption{Table of blas.}
\label{tab:bla}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

File `tab-bla.tex`:

```
%!TeX root=main.tex
\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
Bla & $n$ \\
\midrule
1 & 10 \\
2 & 8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```